# Extract existing and missing left-hand collocates of a word

Tags: r, regex

I'm struggling to extract both existing and missing left-hand collocates of a word such as "like" if "like" is the first word in a string:

```
test_string = c("like like like lucy she likes it and she's always liked it.")
```

Using `str_extract_all` and the negative character class `\\S` I'm getting close - but not close enough (the "l" of the second collocate is curiously omitted):

```
library(stringr)
unlist(str_extract_all(test_string, "(^|\\S+)(?=\\s?\\blike\\b)"))
[1] ""     "ike"  "like"
```

Using this pattern I miss out on the **missing** collocate:

```
unlist(str_extract_all(test_string, "('?\\b[a-z']+\\b|^)(?=\\s?\\blike\\b)"))
[1] "like" "like"
```

The correct result would be this: (`""` stands for the **missing** collocate of the string-initial "like")

```
[1] ""     "like"  "like"
```

I'm wondering, where's the mistake here? How can the extraction be improved?

Comment: If you do not care if the empty match appears at the start or not, you can use `unlist(str_extract_all(test_string, "\\S+(?=\\s+like\\b)|(?<=^like\\b)"))` (as a work-around).

Comment: Let me quickly explain the issue: once an empty match is found, the empty string is returned, and the regex index is advanced to the next position in the string thus disallowing two matches at the same position, an empty string and the word starting at that position.

Comment: I do not have time for this, so a workaround you may try is matching and capturing the items you need. You will need to re-order the captures though. See `res <- str_match_all(test_string, "(^)(?:\\s*(like)\\b)?|(\\S+)(?=\\s+like\\b)")`. If Col 4 is `NA`, take Col 2 and Col 3, else take Col 4.

Comment: `which` returns the empty string position in Wiktor's (first) work around, and suggests a second step `likes[c(which(likes == ""), which(likes != ""))]`, perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of an alternation `|` to get a position at the start of the string and for the matches using a lookbehind assertion with a finite quantifier:

- `^` Start of string (this is the position)
- `(?=like\b)` Positive lookahead, assert `like` followed by a word boundary directly to the right
- `|` Or
- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind

  - `^` Start of string
  - `(?:like\s{1,2}){0,100}` Repeat using a finite quantifier matching like followed by whitespace chars (also followed by a finite quantifier)
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `like\b` Match like and a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/epSwHZ/1) | [R demo](https://tio.run/##TY3NCoMwEITvPsWSS7MgJfZYKr6INMQf2tDgIbtig/XZU9P04GVgvhlmfIw8Emtib6cH1NBL4exrhIPMfQB6ZkdgGcw0JHAiMG4xgX7JsCdngYWznTc@yLzosZgnZ4mT1@ObvelZG@fk4bYEcZdNnVbatsOPbG71Dq4Z0FqVlw1XVVZKbfhvCcQYvw)

Example

```
test_string = c("like like like lucy she likes it and she's always liked it.")
library(stringr)
unlist(str_extract_all(test_string, "^(?=like\\b)|(?<=^(?:like\\s{1,2}){0,100})like\\b"))
```

Output

```
[1] ""     "like" "like"
```